# Changing Task Manager Application Name in FMX

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

When Loaded a FMX application displays the exe name on the Task Manager:

[image: Task Manager with showing my application NaharFMX]

However I can have many of these applications loaded (they are called from another application) and I would like to differentiate them by a context, in my case adding the User Name to it.

Application.Title does not do the trick (actually only changes the title for the icon on the taskbar)

EDIT: to make even clearer my question, I need that the change to be made during run-time, since I do not know previously which user will be connected. The title will be according the User.

EDIT 2: While the explanation of REMY is very good it led me to take a closer look to how my app is running:

[image: Task Manager]

As you see there is no sub tasks available. This is a Server running ThinFinity that is a kind of RDP for application, the app screen is rerouted thru the user´s browser.

The problem here is that I don´t know in this server who is using which application, or if the application went rogue, the Task Manager would be a very easy way to see that. (btw I can see who is connected on the DB server, or in the front end http server, but I cant trace who is who in this server)

Comment: Since the same user is running the app multiple times, won't the app name be the same (exe name+logged in user name)?

Comment: @Rohit I am using ThinFinity, and it executes the same app many times and route the screen, the problem is that I dont know who is using the app (I have a server only to run the apps) it would be very easy using the taskmanager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main entry for an app displays the `FileDescription` value from the app's version info resource, if present, otherwise it displays the filename.  Thus, this text is static and can't be changed at runtime.  This is displaying the name of the app.

However, when you expand an app, it displays the app's actual visible windows, and those sub-entries display whatever text is in their title bars.  For a `TForm` window, that text comes from the `TForm.Caption` property, which you can change dynamically at runtime.

[image: task manager]

You can have multiple instances of the app running, which will have the same app name, but can display different window titles.

[image: multiple instances running]

Answer (score 3):

You must change File Description in Project Options.
Go to Project > Options > Version Info > Find FileDescription and change it into name that you want > OK
[image]

Save and run you app ...
[image]

Comment: I need it to be during runtime execution. Since I can have many running at same time, and want to change it according the context !

Comment: You cannot do that for the top level name in Task Manager - as Vuio says, it comes from the FileDescription